# How to do authentication in ember using php as a backend?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, authentication, ember.js

I have been trying to look for resources that explain how authentication can be done in ember using PHP as a backend.

I have found several other resources that do ember authentication with Rails.

1) [Ember Simple Auth](http://log.simplabs.com/post/57702291669/better-authentication-in-ember-js)

2) [Authentication with EmberJs](http://coderberry.me/blog/2013/07/08/authentication-with-emberjs-part-1/)

3) [Ember Authentication best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14653601/2431285)

4) [Ember Auth](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth)

Any idea on where I can find resources for doing simple authentication using emberJS with PHP?

Thanks! Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a php-specific resource but would suggest starting with the embercast client-side authentication episodes. They focus on how to handle authentication from ember perspective. The "server" part of all this is very simple, it should be very easy to implement in php.

http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1

http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-2